# findall in beautifulsoup isn't working for strings

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to search for specific strings in an HTML page that I scraped. I used the find_all() method in bs4 and provided the string argument, but it doesn't work.

the web page: https://news.google.com/topics/CAAqJggKIiBDQkFTRWdvSUwyMHZNRGx6TVdZU0FtVnVHZ0pKVGlnQVAB?hl=en-IN&gl=IN&ceid=IN%3Aen

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def search(soup):                                                                                                                                        
    results = soup.find_all(string="Union",recursive=True)
    print(len(results))

web_url = "https://news.google.com/topics/CAAqJggKIiBDQkFTRWdvSUwyMHZNRGx6TVdZU0FtVnVHZ0pKVGlnQVAB?hl=en-IN&gl=IN&ceid=IN%3Aen"

r = requests.get(web_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')

search(soup)
```

I get the ouptut of len(results) to be zero. Is my search function wrong?

Comment: I want to achieve this by scraping tho.

Comment: Excuse me for previous misleading comments; the string does occur in the HTML proper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When searching with string argument, you force findall() to find exact matches for each Navigable element. You can do a simpler search for matching substrings using regex logic.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

def search(soup):                                                                                                                                        
    results = soup.find_all(string=re.compile("Union"),recursive=True)
    print(len(results))

web_url = "https://news.google.com/topics/CAAqJggKIiBDQkFTRWdvSUwyMHZNRGx6TVdZU0FtVnVHZ0pKVGlnQVAB?hl=en-IN&gl=IN&ceid=IN%3Aen"

r = requests.get(web_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')

search(soup)
```

For this I get 7 matches

Comment: Thanks,  this works. Btw, what if I want to search for multiple words? How would I go about implementing that?

Comment: I suppose I can't just provide a list of strings I'm searching for in re.compile(). Well, I could just pass the strings in a list to the function one at a time, but is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Regex search logic is a whole beast of itself. searching strings with OR is simpler as you can just do re.compile("Union | cabinet"). But if you need AND it gets a bit more syntactical as you need to declare what order, repetition etc. But there are lots of helpful guides on regex if you just search for it